# add and remove elements from form, 1st click works, subsequent clicks dont

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to add/remove an element to a form based on a checkbox in a previous part of the form.  My problem is, the first time a user clicks on anything in checkContact, the form is appended correctly.  If the user unchecks the box, it is removed correctly.  When the user re-clicks the checkbox, the element is not added..

```
 $('.checkContact').click(function(){
    var addInfo = "<div class='middleRow'><input type='text' id='"+val+"_name[]' name='"+val+"'_name[]'></div>";
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
            alert(addInfo);
            $('#'+divId).append(addInfo);
    }
    else
    {
            $('#'+divId).detach();
            // i have also tried .remove();
    }
```

fiddle:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WHjmL/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `else` part, you are removing the element `$('#' + divId)` from the dom tree instead of removing its content. You have to only empty the container element because in the `if` block you are adding the target markup to the container element.

```
$('.checkContact').click(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var divId = val + '_div';
    var addInfo = "<div class='middleRow'><input type='text' id='" + val + "_name[]' name='" + val + "'_name[]'></div>";
    if (this.checked) {
        //alert(addInfo);
        $('#' + divId).html(addInfo);
    } else {
        //you are removing the container instead of removing its content
        $('#' + divId).empty();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Vk69U/)

Answer (score 2):

When you uncheck the box, you remove `name_div` from the DOM with `.detach`. So when you click the box again, the selector doesn't find anything, so there's nothing to append to.

Change `.detach()` to `.empty()`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/WHjmL/1/)

But perhaps a better method would be to hide and show the DIV, rather than add and remove the content.

Comment: got it, thank you.  i thought about hiding, however its a form, and i dont want to post empty data, so removing it was the best option.  agreed?

Comment: Hidden fields don't get submitted.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have used detach() or empty(), it would remove the element from the DOM and after that you will not be able to insert html by using .html() method. Instead of using detach() or remove() you have to use .empty() or .html(''), this will keep the element in DOM, so you can again and again append the element.

```
$('.checkContact').click(function(){
    var addInfo = "<div class='middleRow'><input type='text' id='"+val+"_name[]' name='"+val+"'_name[]'></div>";
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
            alert(addInfo);
            $('#'+divId).append(addInfo);
    }
    else
    {
            $('#'+divId).html('');
            //or   $('#'+divId).empty();

    }
});
```

see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/WYmVU/